# Vba, "This network connection has files open or requests pending"

Tags: vba

If I run the following, it works and removes the network drive,

```
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive "A:"
```

However if I run this,

```
If Len(Dir("A:\", vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
    Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive "A:"
End If
```

I get the following error,

```
"This network connection has files open or requests pending"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Dir`, try this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
If fso.DriveExists("A") Then
    Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive "A:"
End If
```